# apt-get update reports that http://ppa.launchpad.net list is being updated but there isn't an entry in the sources.list

Tags: debian, apt

I am trying to update Debian 6.5 and get the following errors.

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Sources         
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main amd64 Packages  
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-en_US 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-en    
Get:6 http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy/main amd64 Packages [5,841 kB]                                                      
Get:7 http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-en [3,846 kB]                                                      
Get:8 http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy-updates/main Sources [14 B]                                                         
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                                 
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex                                                 
Fetched 15.9 MB in 19s (805 kB/s)                                                                                         
W: Failed to fetch     http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

However I looked in /etc/apt/sources.list and this is the entire content.

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20130504-14:43]/ wheezy main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20130504-14:43]/ wheezy main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
```

Could update be using the wrong file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, is not. There two places where you can add repositories. The `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any file ending in `.list` in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory (if you add an entry in the `apt.conf` file you can add more, but the ones before are the default). So, just check the files in the directory and remove the one you don't need.

On the other hand, LaunchPad doesn't build Debian packages, so I don't recommend using packages from any of LaunchPad PPA's.